# SQL: Swap MUTUALLY EXCLUSIVE columns?

Tags: sql, multiple-columns, swap

I have a table with columns NAME and ID. For example,

```
[ID] [NAME]
 1   John Lee
 2   Ben Smith
```

I want to switch the NAMEs of the two users (their IDs will remain the same). However, the database I am working with does not allow two users to have the same NAME (not even NULL), so I can't set "Ben Smith" to "John Lee" unless no user has NAME "John Lee".

I suppose I could just do it via PHP and store both of their names in a variable, then make a query to change the two NAMEs to something random, and then assign the swapped NAMEs to the users.

But is there a more elegant way?

Comment: Have you tried using a transaction block?

Comment: SQL implementations often have a way to create a 'transaction' which contains multiple complex steps which all take effect at the end of the transaction.  A lot depends upon your SQL server's vendor and what its syntax allows--e.g., suppressing integrity checks until both changes have been made.

Comment: Can you just drop the unique constraint, do your job, and then add it again?

Comment: I don't have access to changing the constraint, but I can ask (it's 12am though). I want to observe if SQL provides capabilities for dealing with situations such as these - hence the thread.

Comment: Using a transaction or transaction block does not turn off unique constraints.   they are still applied for each individual statement.  He just needs to update both records in one update statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a case expression

```
Update Table set
  name = case name 
         when 'John Lee' then 'Ben Smith'
         when 'Ben Smith' then 'John Lee' End
From table 
Where name in ('John Lee', 'Ben Smith')
```

Answer (score 0):

I have this solution. It replaces the names in one transaction.

```
DECLARE @names AS TABLE (id INTEGER, name VARCHAR(50), UNIQUE(name))

INSERT INTO @names (id, name) VALUES (1, 'John')
INSERT INTO @names (id, name) VALUES (2, 'Ben')


UPDATE N SET name = N2.name
FROM @names N
INNER JOIN (VALUES(1,2),(2,1)) S (old, new) ON N.id = S.old
INNER JOIN @names N2 ON S.new = N2.id

SELECT * FROM @names
```